# How to make back button work in android using jqueymobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, back-button

I have an application in which i'm using jquery-mobile which has a header and it has 2 buttons **"home"** and **"back"** and when i click on back button it should terminate the page and should go back but this is not happening. Can anyone please help me how to make this possible with jquery mobile back button.

My code:

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
   <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-add-back-btn="true">
      <a id="backBtn" href="#" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
      <h1>SDCard Explorer</h1>
      <a id="homeBtn" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-transition="pop">Home</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here are the jquery libraries which i used:

```
<href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" />
<src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
```

Comment: please put your code here. Also it would be better if you can simulate it using www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @uDaY Hi i added a snippet of my code can u please see that once.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
     <!--here links to the jQuery Mobile Library -->
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="Page" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
     <a href="#YourWishPage" class="BackButton" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
      <h1>Tite</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi i added my code above and i think i followed the same procedure but its not working.

Comment: You do not have class="BackButton" in your coude try with my code that works for me I have also android

Comment: <src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" /> must be with >>>>http:/ / code.<<<<<

Comment: Thank you i'll try that and one more thing i have only one html and many function with data-role="page" and in href i don't want to specify any page name it should always go to the previous page.How to do that any idea?

Comment: Can u please tell me where should i give history.go(-1); in js file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <!--here links to the jQuery Mobile Library -->
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Page" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
     <a href="javascript:GoBack()" class="BackButton" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
    <h1>Tite</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

here the function in the JS File

```
function GoBack(){
    history.go(-1);
}
```

it should work in the art